# How to remove regular strips

Tags: image

I want to remove the regular strips of the image as shown as follow. I try many methods, and they do not work, such as image media filter and FFT filter.

Could you tell me how to remove the strips?

[image: Mesh screen hell]

Answer (score 0):

All that black is removing a ton of information from the image.  You have two options available - either re-capture that missing information in a new shot, or attempt to invent / synthesize / extrapolate the missing information with software.

If you can re-shoot, get your camera as close to the mesh fence as you can, use the largest aperture your lens supports to have the shallowest possible depth of field, and set your focus point as deep as possible - this will minimize the appearance of the mesh.

If that is the only still you have to work with, you've got a few dozen hours of playing with the clone and blur tools in front of you in just about any image editing software package you like.

Photoshop would be my go to tool of choice for this.  In Photoshop CS5 they introduced something called [content aware fill](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/content-aware-fill-cs5/).  I'm not sure if it will help you in this specific case because there is SO MUCH black that Adobe's algorithm may think other parts of the mesh are valid sources for filling in the mesh you're trying to clear out.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I want to use algorithm to remove these black strips. Now, I could not find a method to solve it.